# how to use inplace = True in where condition of numpy in dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
df['Partner_salary'] = np.where(df['Partner_working'] == "Yes" ,df.Partner_salary.fillna(df.Partner_salary.median(),inplace=True),0)
```

Comment: `inplace = True` should in general be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Using inplace=True will return "None" and update the the df internally.
So

```
df.Partner_salary.fillna(df.Partner_salary.median(),inplace=True)
```

will return None and code will fail.

Solution:
Either remove inplace=True from the line above or make them two separate lines like

```
df.Partner_salary.fillna(df.Partner_salary.median(),inplace=True)
df['Partner_salary'] = np.where(df['Partner_working'] == "Yes" ,df['Partner_salary'],0)
```